# Referencing HTML scriplet in google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, template-engine

I can't figure out an elementary mistake. When I run the following script the output I get is: `<?= head1 ?>    <?= head2 ?>`
.

I'm trying to make `head1` and `head2` printing scriptlets where it references the google apps script and prints the relevant value defined in the google apps script.

Google Apps Script:

```
function openPage() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Sample Heading');
  var question = 0;
  var answer = 1;
  var category = 2;
  var to_publish = 3;
  var publish_date = 4;

  var questions_faq = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FAQs");
  var heading_1 = questions_faq.getRange("A1").getValue;
  var heading_2 = questions_faq.getRange("B1").getValue;
  var questions = questions_faq.getRange("A2:B" + questions_faq.getLastRow()).getValues();
  html.head1 = heading_1;
  html.head2 = heading_2; 

  
}
```

and my html script is here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><?= head1 ?></th>
    <th><?= head2 ?></th>
  </tr>
</table>
<main></main>
<script> src = "Code.gs" </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## *SUGGESTION*

In my understanding, you want the values of `A1` to be the `head1` & `B1` as the `head2` in your HTML file when shown on a sheet dialog window. You may try this tweaked script below.

### Tweaked Script

```
function openPage() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  var question = 0;
  var answer = 1;
  var category = 2;
  var to_publish = 3;
  var publish_date = 4;

  var questions_faq = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FAQs");
  var heading_1 = questions_faq.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var heading_2 = questions_faq.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var questions = questions_faq.getRange("A2:B" + questions_faq.getLastRow()).getValues();
  html.head1 = heading_1;
  html.head2 = heading_2;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(), 'Sample Heading')
}
```

> ***This answer was derived from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37065873)***

### Demonstration

- After running the script:

[image]

### Reference

- [createTemplateFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createtemplatefromfilefilename)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function openPage() {f
  var tempt = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Sample Heading');
  var question = 0;
  var answer = 1;
  var category = 2;
  var to_publish = 3;
  var publish_date = 4;

  var questions_faq = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FAQs");
  var heading_1 = questions_faq.getRange("A1").getValue;
  var heading_2 = questions_faq.getRange("B1").getValue;
  var questions = questions_faq.getRange("A2:B" + questions_faq.getLastRow()).getValues();
  temp.head1 = heading_1;
  temp.head2 = heading_2; 
  temp.evaluate(); 
}
```